# recognise @param in Eclipse for c++?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, javadoc

I am using Eclipse (3.5.1), on Ubuntu 9.10  to write some C++ code.
I was searching through endless settings but didnt find what I as looking for...

How can I force eclipse to make @param,(@see, @return etc) to be bold in the comments?

All the documentation will be generated with the doxygen so I dont really need anything else. 
Just a small thing to make work easier.

Thanks :)

Comment: I didnt know that there is doxygen plugin, I enabled it in options and its all working just fine.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: no worries. Don't forget to mark answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do

```
/**
 * @param foo
 ...
```

In Eclipse (Version: 3.5.1) I get

[comment http://ploader.net/files/b39ff20600cf04990b80d3ef2f6e6592.png](http://ploader.net/files/b39ff20600cf04990b80d3ef2f6e6592.png)

With the doxygen plugin enabled for the project. Note the double asterisks.